# Select multiple rows for a SELECT JOIN SQL PHP

Tags: mysql

I am doing a query to select the posts of a social network, where each publication can have multiple media files that are in another table. Using JOIN, I create a query that returns me as publications, and also the author of the publication. But how could it obtain the lines corresponding to the various images from the same publication?

```
    SELECT  publicacoes.id,
            publicacoes.id_usuario,
            publicacoes.texto,
            publicacoes.reacoes_count,
            publicacoes.comentarios_count,
            publicacoes.data_postagem,
            publicacoes.tipo,
            NOW() AS agora,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), DATE(publicacoes.data_postagem)) AS diferenca_minutos,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), DATE(publicacoes.data_postagem)) AS diferenca_horas,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, NOW(), DATE(publicacoes.data_postagem)) AS diferenca_meses,
            DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(publicacoes.data_postagem)) AS diferenca_dias,
            publicacoes_midia.id AS id_midia,
            publicacoes_midia.url_arquivo,
            publicacoes_midia.tipo AS tipo_midia,
            usuarios.id AS id_usuario_publicacao,
            usuarios.nome,
            usuarios.apelido,
            usuarios.coord_lat,
            usuarios.coord_lon,
            usuarios.foto_perfil
            FROM publicacoes AS publicacoes 
            JOIN publicacoes_midia AS publicacoes_midia 
            JOIN usuarios AS usuarios
            ON publicacoes.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND publicacoes.id = publicacoes_midia.id
            ORDER BY publicacoes.id DESC LIMIT 36
```

The above query works, but it only brings the first image found in the "publicacoes_midia" table

Answer (score 0):

You should do the 'ON' part for each join
Plus if you want to retrieve plublication that does not contains image, use left join:

```
  SELECT  ...
  FROM publicacoes AS publicacoes 
  LEFT JOIN publicacoes_midia AS publicacoes_midia ON publicacoes.id = publicacoes_midia.id
  LEFT JOIN usuarios AS usuarios  ON publicacoes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
  ORDER BY publicacoes.id DESC LIMIT 36
```